# load URL in to webview of a local file

Tags: javascript, xcode, webview

I am able to load up a local files from iTunes file sharing such as "index.htm" in to a webview

My problem lies when I try to open link from a search text uitextbox. Here, I search the string "mow now"

```
NSString *currentURL = [viewWeb.request.URL absoluteString];
//cleanup
NSString *match = @"Documents/";
NSString *preTel;
NSString *postTel;

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:currentURL];
[scanner scanUpToString:match intoString:&preTel];
NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@contents/search.htm?search=%@&menu=0&submitType=Search", preTel,fixedSpaces];
```

file:///var/mobile/Applications/################/contents/search.htm?search=mow+now&menu=0&submitType=Search

### = my iphone sandbox code (I think?)

```
NSString *fullURL = finalString;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
```

.. and page does not load. :(

Comment: ok tried exactly what you have here and it works for me. The code is correct IMO. is viewWeb set and visible? Is the filename corrrect -- its case sensitive... are you blocking the main thread?

Comment: Yup. Everything is loading but the "search.htm?..." is not loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED: what was missing was "Documents" (case sensitive) in stringWithFormat.

```
NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Documents/contents
                         /search.htm?search=%@&menu=0&submitType=Search",
                           preTel,fixedSpaces];
```